# How to generate PDF forms in Ruby-on-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, pdf-generation, prawn

I would like to generate PDF forms with *radio buttons* and *submit buttons* in it by using Ruby on Rails. Does anyone know if there is a Gem that can help with this task?

I've looked into

- [Prawn](http://prawnpdf.org/),
- [Wicked PDF](http://mileszs.com/wicked-pdf-plugin/), and
- [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit)

but they don't seem to have this feature. Currently I am just using Acrobat Pro to create my PDF and insert the form manually but would like to automate this with a Gem if possible.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**
I just found 2 gems that can help insert radio buttons, check boxes, etc. while generating a PDF in rails: [prawn-blank](https://github.com/hannesg/prawn-blank) and [prawn-forms](https://github.com/yob/prawn-forms). It doesn't seem like they are being maintained anymore but they should still be useful. Hope this is useful for others attempting to automate generating interactive PDF files too.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [RTeX](http://rtex.rubyforge.org/). That works well if you're willing to translate to [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) first. LaTeX is a very good way to store marked-up documents. It just depends on how static each document is.

Comment: I was thinking of using something like the [prawn-forms](https://github.com/yob/prawn-forms) gem but unfortunately this gem does not seem to have a way to insert radio buttons into the pdf. Does anyone know of any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You can use right-signature to complete your task

https://github.com/rightsignature/rightsignature-api

http://www.gsubbarao.com/2013/03/ruby-rightsignature-api-to-prefill.html